Maven test case is not running due to selinium driver
I'm encountering an issue with running my test cases using an extension(Test runner for java). I maintain a ChromeDriver inside a 'driver' folder in the root directory.
Previously, everything worked fine. However, after updating Chrome to version 126.0.6478.55 and downloading the corresponding ChromeDriver version, my test cases still fail to run.
Error:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Starting ChromeDriver 126.0.6478.55 (7616ff175414646cbd1ac65e912fc530b19cc573-refs/branch-heads/6478@{#1402}) on port 29714
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jun 13, 2024 11:52:45 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
INFO: Unable to drain process streams. Ignoring but the exception being swallowed follows.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: The stop timeout of 2000 ms was exceeded (Exit value: -559038737)

